# How to reset the device information in Google Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I was using Samsung Galaxy with android, then I bought the new Motorola DROID RAZR using same SIM card.

when I'm trying to download any app from Google Play Store, it still refers to my previous device. How would I update my device information?

Answer (score 2):

You can visit the [accounts](https://play.google.com/store/account) page in your computer and click on "Settings" tab. Under "My Devices" section you will have all the devices that your account is being tied with.

Answer (score 2):

Common causes that prevent your device from being presented at your devices list are:

- You're using the Google Play website before using the Google Play Store app on your device.
- You're signed in with a different account on play.google.com than you're using on your device.
- Your device isn’t [supported](https://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?answer=1727131). <sup>(DROID RAZR is supported)</sup>

The first one probably solves your issue of registering the device within Google Play Store.

After, you can manage your devices and disable the old one. Access your [account](https://play.google.com/store/account), click the "Settings" tab and untick the "Shown in menus" checkbox.

**References:** [Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1141080)